# I want to use `backward` multiple times in pytorch, but I get an error and cannot run the neural network successfully

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I want to use `backward` multiple times in pytorch, but I get an error and cannot run the neural network successfully.
The error below is the reason why it does not work.

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: 
[torch.FloatTensor [32, 2]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead.
Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. 
The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

I have tried to resolve this error by checking the following website to try and resolve the error, but without success. What should I do?

- [discuss.pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-pytorch1-5-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/90256)
- [discuss.pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation-torch-cuda-floattensor-1-1-256-256-which-is-output-0-of-relubackward0-is-at-version-1-expected-version-0-instead/143490/5)
- [discuss.pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation-torch-cuda-floattensor-256-which-is-output-0-of-asstrid-edbackward0-is-at-version-4-expected-version-3-instead/142130/3)
- [discuss.pytorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-pytorch1-5-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/90256/23?page=2)
- https://nieznanm.medium.com/runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-85d0d207623

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm.notebook import trange
from torchvision import transforms

x_1 = np.arange(0, 2 + 1e-2, 1e-5) 
x_2 = np.arange(0, 1 + 5e-2, 5e-2)
product_train = cartesian((x_1,x_2))
product_initial_condition0 = cartesian((np.array([0.]), x_2))
product_initial_condition1 = cartesian((np.array([2e-6]), x_2))
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
x1 = torch.tensor(product_train[:,0].astype(np.float32), requires_grad=True).to(device)
x2 = torch.tensor(product_train[:,1].astype(np.float32)).to(device)
initial_condition0 = torch.tensor(product_initial_condition0.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
initial_condition0_output = torch.tensor(product_initial_condition0[:,1].astype(np.float32)).to(device)


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(2, 32)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(32, 2)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):   
        inputs = torch.stack([x1,x2], dim=1)
        x = self.linear1(inputs)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)  
        x = self.linear2(x)
        
        return x

NN = Model()
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
NN.to(device)

def f(x1, x2, NN):
    initial_conditon_Phi0 = NN(initial_condition0[:,0], initial_condition0[:,1])
    loss1 = ms_erorr(initial_conditon_Phi0[:,0], initial_condition0_output)
    loss2 = ms_erorr(initial_conditon_Phi0[:,1], initial_condition0_output)

    return loss1, loss2

def train(NN, optimizer, iteration):
    with trange(iteration) as t:
        torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
        for i in t:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            a1, a2 = f(x1, x2, NN)
            a1.backward(retain_graph=True)
            optimizer.step()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            a2.backward()        
            optimizer.step()
            t.set_postfix(a1=a1.item(), a2=a2.item())

    return NN

iteration = 1000
optimizer = optim.Adam(NN.parameters(), lr=0.001)
ms_erorr = nn.MSELoss()
NN= train(NN, optimizer, iteration)
```

---

This neural network model has two inputs and two outputs; for each of the two outputs, I want to create a model that outputs an arbitrary value. However, there is a situation where I want to learn the values of the two outputs separately, instead of learning the values of the two outputs at the same time, so I want to be able to train the neural network successfully using `backward()` twice. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve (data flow and loss computations, what needs to be updated by which loss term, etc...).

Comment: You use `optimizer.zero_grad` before doing `a2.backward`. `zero_grad` zeroes out the gradient, so doing backwards afterwards to propagate the gradient doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The result of adding the value of `a1.backward` and the value of `a2.backward` (in effect, `a1.backward` has been executed twice, hasn't it?) I thought, so I added `optimizer.zero_grad()`. Also, even if I delete `optimizer.zero_grad()`, the above error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are updating the network (optimizer.step) before finishing back propagation. You need first backpropagate all the errors you've got on the previous step, and then do the update. This can be the source of an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What exactly should we do about it?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you code is supposed to do, so it's hard to answer, but are you sure you need to do optimizer.step before a2.backward ?